# HTML Video has trasparent grey overlay on top

Tags: html, css, video, browser, shopify

How do you remove this trasparent overlay on top of the video using CSS?
[see overlay (very subtle)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaaYp.png)

html code:
`<div data-pf-type="HTML.Video" class="sc-khQegj xLZop pf-17_"><video width="100%" type="video/mp4?v=1680101963" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0727/5128/4563/t/2/assets/file.mp4?v=1680101963" loop="" muted="" playsinline="" autoplay="" controlslist="nodownload" disablepictureinpicture=""></video></div>`

Strage how on mobile there is not an overlay and the overlay color changes from browser to browser
I think it has to do with controls / selection but i don't know

I tried changing the video background color and other css stuuf but they don't work

css currently:

```
element.style {
}
.xLZop video {
display: flex;
height: auto;
border-radius: inherit;
}

.fWMPub[class*=pf-c-], .xLZop video {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
}

.__pf img, .__pf video {
max-width: 100%;
border: 0;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.__pf *, .__pf :after, .__pf :before {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
img, video {
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
border-style: none;
vertical-align: top;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
box-sizing: border-box!important;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

video[Attributes Style] {
width: 100%;
}

user agent stylesheet
video {
object-fit: contain;
overflow-clip-margin: content-box;
overflow: clip;
}
```

Comment: You should add your css as well, so we can see what you've done so far.

Comment: @ShanieMoonlight added the current css on the site, i did not write it myself

Comment: You're going to need to find the css for the element you're interested in. The you'll be able to change the color/opacity/etc to suit your own needs. Have a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TYYB8s4uUI4